# Show Yoast SEO meta tags in Custom WordPress Templates (Theme)

Tags: theme-development, page-template, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I overwrote twenty nineteen theme in WordPress and included all my templates.
After that, I installed the Yoast SEO plugin to add dynamic meta tags to pages created using custom templates.

I have common header.php and have included it in all templates. Now I want to show Yoast SEO meta tags in all custom template pages.

How to do it?

Comment: Does your header.php file have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` inside the `<head>` element. It's required for WordPress themes.

Comment: Yes it has `wp_head()` function

Comment: Then Yoast should be able to add tags itself. Which meta tags are you talking about?

Comment: meta description and meta keywords. I have added default meta description and meta keywords in header.php. Should I remove that?

Comment: Yes. Yoast does not automatically. Except for keywords. Keywords in Yoast are not meta keywords, which are useless.

Comment: what does it means - "Keywords in Yoast are not meta keywords" ?

Comment: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/the-difference-between-focus-keywords-and-meta-keywords/

Comment: Thank you so much for this help @JacobPeattie And can you please tell me how I can show meta description and title of yoast in my custom theme?

Comment: As I have already said twice now, Yoast adds these tags to the `<head>` automatically.

Comment: Okay thanks I got it and resolved it. Many thanks.